# Objective-C: NSURLConnection, when to starting working with the response?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

When using NSURLConnection, there are several methods to be watching... I understand that `connection:didReceiveResponse:` could potentially be fired several times during a connection.

At what point is it safe to start working with the received information? Within `connectionDidFinishLoading:`?

In my project, I am appending the received data in `connection:didReceiveData:` by setting:
`// append the data
[receivedData appendData:data];`

Then I'm actually doing stuff with the results within the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` ... creating my NSDictionary with TouchJSON, looping through the data and changing my UI.

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connectionDidFinishLoading` is the correct place to start working with the received data.

`didReceiveData` is the correct place to append the newly received data (not `didReceiveResponse`).

`didReceiveResponse` is a good place to check HTTP status codes etc.

Comment: Ah yes... my mistake. I was actually appending the data in `didReceiveData` . Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really require an asynchronous connection for the task you are performing?  If all you are doing in `connection:didReceiveResponse:` is appending the data to a buffer, then you're really not gaining anything by using an asynchronous request.

Why not just detach a thread that uses `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` instead?  Then your thread can invoke a callback when it has the data (or when it has errored out), and there's no need to worry about when it's safe to start working with the response.

If, on the other hand, you had a streaming JSON parser that could parse the data as it was downloading, it would make sense to use an asynchronous request and feed the data to the parser as you got it.  That would require less memory since you wouldn't need to buffer the entire response, and would seem faster at runtime because some of the parsing is being done while the data is being downloaded.  In such a case, you would use `connection:didReceiveResponse:` to feed data to your parser instead of appending it to a buffer, and then `connectionDidFinishLoading:` to tell your parser that there is no more data for it to parse.

Comment: `NSURLConnection`'s default mode is asynchronous. The synchronous mode runs _on top of_ the asynchronous methods -- it blocks the original thread, and then spawns a new thread. The asynchronous mode already handles the threading for you, and does the callbacks on the original thread anyways. Why on earth would you want to do that by hand?

Comment: @Josh Caswell - Because it takes less code and less complexity to detach a thread that makes a synchronous request than it does to add `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods that just replicate functionality that is already built-in to `NSURLConnection`.  If all you care about is the completed response, it is much more clear from a coding perspective to say "get me the response" than it is to say "start a connection and send me data periodically so that I can buffer it and construct the response myself".

Comment: Mmm... yes... I think I'll stick to `NSURLConnection` just the way it is.

Comment: The delegate methods are all optional -- you only have to implement `didRecieveData:` if that's all you want. How is creating a new thread, which is then going to have to manually call back to methods (which, the way you're describing, mimic the delegate methods) on the original thread, less complex than that?

Comment: @Josh Caswell - The delegate methods are only "all optional" if you don't care about getting any data.  But regardless, creating a new thread is also optional (the downloader may already be running in its own thread, or the operation may be of the sort that it is appropriate to block the app), and as simple as a `performSelectorInBackground` call.  And adding your own callback can be more clear because you can name it something contextually relevant, like `parseJson`.  Of course, you could have `connectionDidFinishLoading:` call `parseJson`, but then you're adding `parseJson` in either case.

Comment: It's _never_ appropriate to block the main thread. The system [will kill your app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1693/_index.html) if your synchronous request takes too long. I have no idea what you mean by your scare quotes around _all optional_; the methods are optional. You only implement the ones you need. Full stop. Your suggestion may improve readability, but it means re-implementing the delegate functionality. You're also ignoring the question of how your callback is going to get back to the original thread.

Comment: @Josh Caswell - I meant "block the app" in the sense of showing a loading spinner and disabling user interaction until the data loads, but point taken.  The way I stated it was not clear.  As for the optional thing, *if you care about the data the request returns* (almost always the case) then you need to implement at least a couple delegate methods.  That they are declared optional is irrelevant; you can't omit them all **and** do something useful, so for practical purposes, *some* are required.  And to get back to the main thread, do: `performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parseJson)...`.

Comment: And if it wasn't on the main thread to begin with, as you mentioned? "_If you care about the data_", you have to implement some callbacks, whether you use the ones that Apple has named "delegate methods", or do it the way you're talking about. You're literally suggesting re-implementing the NSURLConnection functionality by hand just so you can rename a method. It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Josh Caswell - "You're literally suggesting re-implementing the NSURLConnection functionality"; now that's where I disagree.  If you implement `connection:didReceiveData:` to just call `[receivedData appendData:data];` then you are reimplementing functionality that is built-in to `NSURLConnection`.  It will do this for you automatically if you use the synchronous method.  It doesn't really make sense to implement a delegate method to do something that the class can already do for you, and you don't really need async I/O if you're just buffering the data in memory until you have it all.